# Why can't I nest these if statement?

Tags: data-science-model

this is: I am trying to nest the following if statements =IF(ISBLANK(E2),"",IF((TODAY()-$A2)>=7,IF(REGEXMATCH($I2,"ORDERED|ordered|order number|PO#|PO|purchase order|po|p.o"),"Request Ordered",$E2&" Requested Not Ordered"),"")) based upon a number of conditions: 1st cell e2 is populated then the date in a2 must be greater than or equal to 7days. It these conditions are met then I need to combine this additional if in the nest: =IF(ISBLANK(J3),"Request Ordered","Request Order Complete")

Comment: Try formatting that so the code is more readable, and also share what language you are talking because rules are different in different languages.

Comment: this is using Google sheets and I need to nest or combine the 2 if groups together

Comment: I cannot help with google sheets, out of my depth, sorry about that

Comment: You might get more eyes on this in the regular StackOverflow though!

Comment: thanks for the heads up...have a great day!!